# MicroK8s Can Not Connect To Server

Tags: kubernetes, microk8s

I was attempting to get the dashboard pod enabled on a new microk8s cluster.

[How to access micro8ks's dashboard web UI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1123996/how-to-access-micro8kss-dashboard-web-ui)

I am trying to just get some basic info

```
microk8s kubectl cluster-info
```

and get this

```
E0331 18:08:44.908516   10120 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://10.0.2.15:16443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 10.0.2.15:16443: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```